# Failed to resolve import "styled-components"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I was going through Mosh Hamedan's beginner React course and I got to "Styling components" where I was instructed to use styled-components

I tried to download it through the bult-in terminal in VS code and wrote:-

`npm install styled-components`

Then Imported the file:-

`import styled from "styled-components";`

I got an error on "styled-components" which was solved in the course by writing:-

`npm install @types/styled-components`

It worked and the error was gone but when I tried to open the Page this is what I got :-

[image]